# How to send bulk emails to predetermined recipients?

Tags: email

How is it possible that my college sends email to "branch_name@collegedomain.com" and it is sent to all students of that branch? There are several emails like "year_batch@collegedomain.com" and it reaches all students of that year's batch with different college emails for e.g. "name1@collegedomain.com", "name2@collegedomain.com" etc. How is it possible and how to implement this?

Comment: @Anaksunaman yes, I too believe. Can you suggest some software as I couldn't find one. To make it more clear, I would add that when I receive an email from the college, the receivers address is not mine but "branch_name@collegedomain.com" and others of the same branch also receive it. ALSO, is it possible that instead of a software, "branch_name@collegedomain.com" represents all emails and anyone in the world sending an email to this email will send emails to all the students of that branch.

Comment: @Anaksunaman it means maybe the college has created it's own program and email lists and distributed to dean's and professors so that they can send these bulk mails.

Comment: That is certainly a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

> How is it possible and how to implement this?

Rereading your question, is seems likely that automatic forwarding is a possibility. In case it matters, the automatic forwarding I mention where a single address is forwarded to multiple recipients may be called a [distribution list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_list) or possibly referred to as an [electronic mailing list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_mailing_list). Distribution lists can be a feature of email clients or (in some cases) email servers. [Electronic mailing lists may use dedicated software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mailing_list_software).

It's also possible to "roll your own" software or script. For instance, one such solution might be to use [Python](https://www.python.org/) with [imaplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html) and either [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) or a combination of [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) with a command line mailer to automatically download and redistribute emails sent to a particular server. Several of the electronic mailing list program entries in the Wikipedia link above use a similar idea (i.e. they are based around scripting languages).